# Static routes configured in Netplan bouncing DHCP lease files

Tags: dhcp, netplan

I configure static routes on a DHCP interface using Netplan on Ubuntu 20.04 as followings:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens4:
            dhcp4: true
            routes:
            -   to: 10.1.1.1
                via: 192.168.1.1
```

The static route works. However, it causes DHCP lease file bouncing every 3 seconds.

```
$ ls -la --time-style=full-iso /run/systemd/netif/leases/3
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-network systemd-network 315 2023-11-15 22:44:52.537783405 +0000 /run/systemd/netif/leases/3
$ls -la --time-style=full-iso /run/systemd/netif/leases/3
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-network systemd-network 315 2023-11-15 22:44:56.141554573 +0000 /run/systemd/netif/leases/3
```

As a result, the ntp-systemd-netif.service keeps restarting every 3 seconds.

```
Nov 15 22:47:16 ... systemd[1]: ntp-systemd-netif.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 15 22:47:16 ... systemd[1]: ntp-systemd-netif.service: Failed with result 'start-limit-hit'.
```

I wonder why this configuration causes DHCP lease file to change every 3 seconds.  Is static route configured on DHCP interface supported by Netplan?

Thanks
Hung

Comment: Please see `https://netplan.io` and `https://netplan.io/examples`.

Comment: Are you sure it's because of the static route? If you remove the static route entry does the problem go away?

Comment: Yes.  When I remove static routes and the DHCP lease files stops getting updated.

Comment: From log, it looks like the static route triggers a configuration update loop. 
Nov 16 14:00:23 ... systemd-networkd[37966]: ens4: State changed: configured -> configuring. 
Nov 16 14:00:23 ... systemd-networkd[37966]: ens4: Routes set. 
Nov 16 14:00:23 ... systemd-networkd[37966]: ens4: State changed: configuring -> configured.